# WrapPanel scrollbars

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, wrappanel

Simple xaml:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow" />
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Green" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Resizing window:

[image]

**How to show vertical and horizontal scrollbars when content doesn't fit?**

Note: this should work for any content.

---

I tried to put it into `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        ...
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

but then `WrapPanel` stops wrapping anything (always one column):

[image]

The problem here is that `ScrollViewer` gives `(NaN, NaN)` size to it child, so wrapping never occurs.

I tried to fix it by binding scroll viewer available height to max height of panel:

```
<ScrollViewer ...>
    <WrapPanel MaxHeight="{Binding ViewportHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}" ...>
```

This will limit panel height (not `NaN` anymore), so wrapping now occurs. But because this also adjust the height of panel - the vertical scrollbar will never appears:

[image]

**How to add vertical scrollbar?**

---

In my case `WrapPanel` is vertical, means it will fill columns as much as it can and then wrap to a new column from left to right. Scrollbars are needed when children doesn't fit either vertically (when available space is less than children height) or horizontally.

The idea thought can be used for a *standard* (horizontal) `WrapPanel`: from left to right, creating new rows when full. Absolutely same problem will arise (just tried it).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what these controls are meant to do. For example, why would you need to wrap if you're scrolling?

Comment: @Ortund, to avoid scrolling as much as possible. But when content doesn't fit (and wrapping won't help) - it should be possible to start scrolling.

Comment: Try putting the WrapPanel in a different container inside the scrollviewer... ScrollViewer > Grid/DockPanel/StackPanel > WrapPanel. See if this makes the scrollviewer scroll the WrapPanel's container rather than the WrapPanel itself. I'd recommend a DockPanel with `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` on the WrapPanel

Comment: Do you know the minimum height of your wrap panel's content or should it be calculated dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

That sort of behavior is not possible with a `WrapPanel` without setting explicitly its `Height`/`MinHeight` for a `Vertical` orientation or `Width`/`MinWidth` for a `Horizontal` orientation. The `ScrollViewer` will only show the scrollbars when the `FrameworkElement` this scroll viewer wraps doesn't fit into the viewport.

You can create your own wrap panel that calculates its minimum size based on its children.

Alternatively, you can implement a `Behavior<WrapPanel>` or an attached property. This won't be as easy as just adding a couple of XAML tags, as you might expect.

We have solved this issue with an attached property. Let me give you an idea of what we did.

```
static class ScrollableWrapPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollableWrapPanel), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));

    // DP Get/Set static methods omitted

    static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (WrapPanel)d;
        if (!panel.IsInitialized)
        {
            panel.Initialized += PanelInitialized;        
        }
        // Add here the IsEnabled == false logic, if you wish
    }

    static void PanelInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (WrapPanel)sender;
        // Monitor the Orientation property.
        // There is no OrientationChanged event, so we use the DP tools.
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
            WrapPanel.OrientationProperty,
            typeof(WrapPanel))
        .AddValueChanged(panel, OrientationChanged);

        panel.Unloaded += PanelUnloaded;

        // Sets up our custom behavior for the first time
        OrientationChanged(panel, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    static void OrientationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (WrapPanel)sender;
        if (panel.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical)
        {
            // We might have set it for the Horizontal orientation
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(panel, WrapPanel.MinWidthProperty);

            // This multi-binding monitors the heights of the children
            // and returns the maximum height.
            var converter = new MaxValueConverter();
            var minHeightBiding = new MultiBinding { Converter = converter };
            foreach (var child in panel.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
            {
                minHeightBiding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ActualHeight") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Source = child });
            }

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(panel, WrapPanel.MinHeightProperty, minHeightBiding);

            // We might have set it for the Horizontal orientation        
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(panel, WrapPanel.WidthProperty);

            // We have to define the wrap panel's height for the vertical orientation
            var binding = new Binding("ViewportHeight")
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(ScrollViewer)}
            };

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(panel, WrapPanel.HeightProperty, binding);
        }
        else
        {
            // The "transposed" case for the horizontal wrap panel
        }
    }

    static void PanelUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (WrapPanel)sender;
        panel.Unloaded -= PanelUnloaded;

        // This is really important to prevent the memory leaks.
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(WrapPanel.OrientationProperty, typeof(WrapPanel))
            .RemoveValueChanged(panel, OrientationChanged);
    }

    private class MaxValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.Cast<double>().Max();
        }

        // ConvertBack omitted
    }
}
```

It is maybe not the easiest way, and there are a little bit more lines that just a few XAML tags, but it works flawlessly.

You have to be careful with the error handling though. I've just omitted all the checks and exception handling in the sample code.

The usage is simple:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" local:ScrollableWrapPanel.IsEnabled="True">
    <!-- Content -->
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer
```

Comment: Interesting idea with using multibinding and multiconverter. One of the problem this solution has - you are not monitoring for `Children` change (if new big child is added), not sure if this can be easily fixed.

Comment: @Sinatr, well, that's definitely possible. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5856140/2846483). You will need to observe the `LayoutUpdated` event. Btw, in your question you didn't mention that you need the wrap panel to monitor its children count.

Comment: Do you think I am going to use red, yellow and green circles in production? =D But you are right, I have problem to ask questions properly. There is easy to miss "note" in the question and in comment to other answer I said MVVM (which can be translated as "Many Very Very Many bindings").

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by wrapping your wrappanel in a scrollviewer, but then binding the height and width of the inner panel to the Height and Width of the Viewport of the scrollviewer, so it stretches and contracts with the rest of the screen.
I've also added minimum Height and Width to my sample, which ensures that the scrollbars appear once the wrap panel is pushed smaller than it's min dimensions

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <WrapPanel MinWidth="200" Width="{Binding ElementName=sv, Path=ViewportWidth}" MinHeight="200" Height="{Binding ElementName=sv, Path=ViewportHeight}">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="200" Width="200"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Yellow" Height="200" Width="200"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Green" Height="200" Width="200"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know `MinWidth` or `MinHeight` values. That would be the difficult in the MVVM world with data templates. Unless making a custom `WrapPanel` to monitor for children sizes.. or using some events.. hmm.. could there be an easier way?

Comment: With this solution, the scrollbars only appear when the window's height or width is lesser than the minimum height and width of the WrapPanel, even though you can no longer see the contents of the WrapPanel long before that happens.

Comment: Would you be thinking that all of the items in the wrap panel would be differing heights and widths or would it be more likely that they'd all be the same size (according to the data template)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems monitoring for children is one of important task to achieve wanted. So why not creating custom panel:

```
public class ColumnPanel : Panel
{
    public double ViewportHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ViewportHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewportHeightProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewportHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewportHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ColumnPanel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var location = new Point(0, 0);
        var size = new Size(0, 0);
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            if (location.Y != 0 && ViewportHeight < location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height)
            {
                location.X = size.Width;
                location.Y = 0;
            }
            if (size.Width < location.X + child.DesiredSize.Width)
                size.Width = location.X + child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (size.Height < location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height)
                size.Height = location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
            location.Offset(0, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }
        return size;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var location = new Point(0, 0);
        var size = new Size(0, 0);
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            if (location.Y != 0 && ViewportHeight < location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height)
            {
                location.X = size.Width;
                location.Y = 0;
            }
            child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));
            if (size.Width < location.X + child.DesiredSize.Width)
                size.Width = location.X + child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (size.Height < location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height)
                size.Height = location.Y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
            location.Offset(0, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

The usage (instead of `WrapPanel`) is following:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <local:ColumnPanel ViewportHeight="{Binding ViewportHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}" ... >
        ...
    </local:ColumnPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The idea is to calculate layout manually, while `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` will be automatically called whenever children are changed: added, deleted, resized, etc.

Measure logic is simple: start from `(0,0)` and measure next child size, if it fits into current column - add it, otherwise start and new column by offsetting location. During whole measurement cycle adjust the resulting size.

The only missing part of puzzle is to provide into measure/arrange cycles `ViewportHeight` from parent `ScrollViewer`. This is the role of `ColumnPanel.ViewportHeight`.

Here is the demo (button add purple circle):

[image]